# Partition By - Sum all values Excluding Maximum Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, partitioning, partition-by

I have data as follows

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | Code | Weight |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | M    |    200 |
|  1 | 2A   |     50 |
|  1 | 2B   |     50 |
|  2 |      |    350 |
|  2 | M    |    350 |
|  2 | 3A   |    120 |
|  2 | 3B   |    120 |
|  3 | 5A   |    100 |
|  4 |      |    200 |
|  4 |      |    100 |
+----+------+--------+
```

For ID `1` the max weight is 200, I want to subtract sum of all weights from ID `1` except the max value that is `200`.

There might be a case when there are 2 rows containing max values for same id. Example for ID `2` we have 2 rows containing max value i.e. `350` . In such scenario I want to sum all values except the max value. But I would mark weight 0 for 1 of the 2 rows containing max value. That row would be the one where `Code` is NULL/Blank.

Case where there is only 1 row for an ID the row would be kept as is.

Another scenario could be one where there is only row containing max weight but `Code` is NULL/Blank in such case we would simply do what we did for ID `1`. Sum all values except max value and subtract from row containing max value.

**Desired Output**

```
+----+------+--------+---------------+
| ID | Code | Weight | Actual Weight |
+----+------+--------+---------------+
|  1 | M    |    200 |           100 |
|  1 | 2A   |     50 |            50 |
|  1 | 2B   |     50 |            50 |
|  2 |      |    350 |             0 |
|  2 | M    |    350 |           110 |
|  2 | 3A   |    120 |           120 |
|  2 | 3B   |    120 |           120 |
|  3 | 5A   |    100 |           100 |
|  4 |      |    200 |           100 |
|  4 |      |    100 |           100 |
+----+------+--------+---------------+
```

I want to create column `Actual Weight` as shown above. I can't find a way to apply partition by excluding max value and create column `Actual Weight`.

Comment: for case `ID = 2`, what if there are more than 2 rows with `Weight = 350` ?

Comment: @Squirrel If there are more than 2 the ones with `Code` that are blank / empty will have actual weight 0.

Comment: Sorry, I mean for case where more than 2 row with Weight - 350 and Code is not blank

Comment: @Squirrel If there are more than 1 rows with max weight apart from 1 containing max all others rows will have blank/null `Code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dense_rank()` to identify the row with max weight, dr = 1 is rows with max weight

`row_number()` to differentiate the max weight row for Code = blank from others

---

```
with cte as
(
    select *, 
           dr = dense_rank() over (partition by ID order by [Weight] desc),
           rn = row_number() over (partition by ID order by [Weight] desc, Code desc)
    from   tbl
)
select *,
       ActWeight = case when dr = 1 and rn <> 1
                        then 0
                        when dr = 1 and rn = 1
                        then [Weight]
                           - sum(case when dr <> 1 then [Weight] else 0 end) over (partition by ID)
                        else [Weight]
                        end
from   cte
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c88bba846ed6a14424d4eed43d8cf322)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you just want window functions and conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by id order by weight desc, (case when code <> '' then 2 else 1 end))
             then weight - sum(case when weight <> max_weight then weight else 0 end) over (partition by id)
             else weight
        end) as actual_weight
from (select t.*,
             max(weight) over (partition by id, code) as max_weight
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Column t.ID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Lopez . . . Oops, left out the window frame specification.

Comment: Please view [results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/043e6/3) from your answer. The subtraction doesn't seems to work.